# Laravel 4: Package Extending Controller

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to package my extending controller into my package. So, I put all my controllers in 'controllers' under 'src' folder.

MyController.php

```
namespace MyVendor\MyPackage;
use \Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
    }
}
```

I tried to call it from route in package with `MyVendor\MyPackage\MyController@loginAction` and it end up with the message "Class MyVendor\MyPackage\MyController does not exist".

What did I missed or done wrong? How to make it works?

Thank you.

Comment: did you add it to the autoload in composer.json and run a `composer dump-autoload` ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: make sure it is being autoloaded via composer.  In composer.json (in your workbench/package):

```
"autoload": {

    // ...

    "classmap": [
        "src/controllers",
    ],

    // ...
},
```

Then run composer dump-autoload from the command line, but make sure you are in the package directory (e.g. workbench/name/package/)!

Step 2: add an alias in /app/config/app.php.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried, but still getting the same error. The part that I don't understand is step 2. What to add in the alias? What I've done here is adding `"MyVendor\MyPackage"=>"MyVendor\MyPackage\Controllers"`. Is that correct?